# How to check which SAML version is being used in Rails Project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saml

The answer to this might be simple but I am unable to find it. In my **Gemfile.lock** file it says **0.7.2**, that is the gem version. But how to get to know if it is SAML **2.0 or 1.1** so that the other team working on a different tech stack can also follow the same version.

Gem used for implementing SAML, [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether Rails project has this feature to tell if it implemented SAML2.0 or SAML1.1, but one can easily check the SAML version thru metadata file.

For SAML2.0:

`<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" .../>`

For SAML1.1:

```
...
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol">
...
```

Also if SAML-Rails project supports SP-initiated web-SSO, Artifact Resolution Protocol thru artifact reference and Single Logout Protocol, then it is SAML2.0, since SAML previous version doesn't support these features.

Comment: I found something like this in `open_saml_response.xml`, `<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idm.orademo.com</saml2:Issuer>`. I guess it means __SAML2.0__. So, we can conclude by saying that atleast from `0.7.x` onwards **SAML 2.0** is used.